# mongodb find() return empty result in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In my node application i am using mongodb for datastorage by using Mongoose.In that the following is my code:

```
 var client = new OAuthClient({"name":"default"});
        client.user = req.user;
        client.username = req.body.username;
        console.log("b4 save");
        client.save();

        OAuthClient.find({username:req.body.username}).exec(function(err, clients) {                
        if (err) {
            res.render('error', {
                status: 500
            });
        } else {
            console.log("clientssssssss=" + util.inspect(clients));
            res.jsonp(clients);
        }
      });
```

But

console.log("clientssssssss=" + util.inspect(clients)); Is returning empty array[].

while i execute the command in my ROBOMONGO the result is returned. suppose  consider my query is like this `OAuthClient.find({username:'user4'})` 
the result is coming, but with the above code its returning empty array. Help me to solve this. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please check, is that query the right collection?

Comment: @ Muhammad Ali Yes is that in correct collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is callbacks as shown here:

```
client.save();   // <-- not waiting for callback

    OAuthClient.find({username:req.body.username}).exec(function(err, clients) {                
    if (err) {
```

You need to wait for the callback as `.save()` is not guaranteed of completion. Do instead:
    client.save(function(err,client) {

```
    OAuthClient.find({username:req.body.username}).exec(function(err, clients) {                
        if (err) {

        }

        //body of work
    });

});
```

Where everything is inside the callback from `.save()`

Comment: @ Neil Lunn r u saying that inside .save function i have to do the find query?? Also can you please align the code correctly what you have posted..

Comment: @Subburaj. Essentially yes. What I am really saying is that the line following `.save()` does not wait for `.save()` to complete. This is asynchronous and only inside the "callback" argument of `.save()` do you know this has completed and the document you are trying to retrieve is actually there.